# Finding restriction in differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[Differential equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCnZE.png)

[Three possible branches of domains](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7D9Db.png)

I have managed to solve this Bernoulli equation and found the general solution for it using integrating factor but I am struggling to understand how the domains are derived. I get that x cannot be 0 because 2/0= 0 However why are there 3 branches? But why are there 3 branches? And what does the symbol E denote? I don't major in Maths, so I find this a bit hard to understand. Thanks